# SSH Connection Closes Immediately After RemoteCommand

Tags: ssh

I have a `.ssh` config file on my MacBook for connecting to a remote Ubuntu server. The config file looks like this:

```
Host remote_computer
    HostName 1.2.3.4
    Port 22
    User remote_username
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    RemoteCommand echo "Hello, World!"
```

Here's what happens when I try to connect:

```
local_computer:/ local_username$ ssh remote_computer
Hello, World!
local_computer:/ local_username$
```

The `RemoteCommand` runs successfully, but then the connection closes immediately after that. This happens with any `RemoteCommand` I try, but if I remove `RemoteCommand` from my config file, the connection stays open:

```
local_computer:/ local_username$ ssh remote_computer
remote_username@remote_computer:~$
```

**Why does the connection close after successfully running the** `RemoteCommand` **from the config file, and what can I do to prevent that**?

Comment: What's your intention, if not to run a command on the remote side? Do you want the remote session to always run something during login?

Comment: From [man ssh](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh): "If a _command_ is specified, it is executed on the remote host instead of a login shell.", which is essentially what this configuration entry is.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. I didn't make the connection between `RemoteCommand` and what @user4556274 pointed out. I think I have a better understanding of the purpose of `RemoteCommand` now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

force a TTY and enter a shell:

```
Host remote_computer
    HostName 1.2.3.4
    Port 22
    User remote_username
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    RemoteCommand echo "Hello, World!" && bash
    RequestTTY force
```

Comment: Docs say it is the config equivalent of specifying -t, so it should work if -t does. https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/r/requesttty.htm

Comment: Maybe "force" ?  `RequestTTY force`

Comment: Ah, then add a shell to the command (edited)

Comment: Good idea, might be better to use `;` instead of `&&` though in case the first command is something different than `echo` and fails

Comment: Thanks! This works really well, though I don't think `force` is necessary—I think the issue was not running bash. But with bash, `RequestTTY yes` works for me. Also, I followed @Jesse_b's advice and replaced the ampersands with a semicolon.